# display a php page after executing it from ajax .post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html page with a form id="date_select" and a div block with id="display".

**index.html**

```
<form id="date_select">
    <span id="date_select">Select date to display forms:</span>
        <input id="date" type="text" />
        <input id="date_submit" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The js code is:

```
   $('#leave_form_date').submit(function()
{
    var date=$('#date').val();
    if(date != '')
    {
         $.post('view_forms.php',{date:date},function(data)
         {
            //dont know what to put
         }

        }
    });
```

The js code sends the date to a php script.

Now, I need to display the entire view_forms.php page after execution in my 'display' div block on the index page

Answer (score 1):

but did you try this:

```
     $.post('view_forms.php',{date:date},function(data)
     {
        $("#display").html(data);
     }
```

Comment: the view_forms.php has a table echoed and I want the table to be displayed in the div block.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the forms already and put them in div and make it display:none in side main div.

Keep div names like

```
 <div id = "form1" style='display:none'>code here ..</div>
 <div id = "form2" style='display:none'>code stuff here</div>
```

from php script return form name to display in data variable and use it in in Ajax return success event. like

```
      $.post('view_forms.php',{date:date},function(data)
     {
        $('#'+data).show();
     }
```

The other solution can be to create a form from php and return it back to ajax success function in data and display it inside desired div.

I donnot have any idea how you are returning respons from PHP but I can give you some idea and you can implement it according to your logic.
it would be like. when you are returning response from PHP. do it like
In ajax when php script is called in php after doing your stuff you can return as under.

```
    $response = '<form name="form1" action="somepage.php">
    email: <input type = "text" name="email" value="'.$somevalue.'">
   </form>' ;

    echo $response
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to return a form from php to .post function?
Im a newbie..pls help
could u write the code

Comment: I don't have a idea how you are retuning or performing your logic in php but i have edited my answer. please try that and see it it works for you